# How to change the default Roll over color of LinkBar

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I am using link bar and by default when I click on the links it shows the blue color in the link background. I want to change this blue color to green color. 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
var colorTransform:ColorTransform = linkbar.transform.colorTransform;
colorTransform.color = 0x009900;
linkbar.transform.colorTransform = colorTransform;
linkbar.alpha = .2
```

Or create a custom button like this:

```
LinkButton
{
    textRollOverColor: #006699;
    textSelectedColor: #003366;
    /* Yes, this one controls the selected button's text color */
    disabledColor: #0099cc;

    /*Use DownSkin for Disabled to simulate Active/Selected Button */
    disabledSkin: Embed(source="theme1.swf", symbol="LinkButton_downSkin");
    downSkin: Embed(source="theme1.swf", symbol="LinkButton_downSkin");
    overSkin: Embed(source="theme1.swf", symbol="LinkButton_overSkin");
    upSkin: Embed(source="theme1.swf", symbol="LinkButton_upSkin");
    font-size: 14;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```